# Why HATEOAS starts creating issue for spring-boot version >= 2.2.x during startup with Swagger 2.x?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, spring-hateoas

I moved my project from spring-boot 2.1.9 to 2.2.0.

While starting the project, I am facing the below `error` messages.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry<org.springframework.hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverer, org.springframework.http.MediaType>' available: expected single matching bean but found 17: modelBuilderPluginRegistry,modelPropertyBuilderPluginRegistry,typeNameProviderPluginRegistry,syntheticModelProviderPluginRegistry,documentationPluginRegistry,apiListingBuilderPluginRegistry,operationBuilderPluginRegistry,parameterBuilderPluginRegistry,expandedParameterBuilderPluginRegistry,resourceGroupingStrategyRegistry,operationModelsProviderPluginRegistry,defaultsProviderPluginRegistry,pathDecoratorRegistry,apiListingScannerPluginRegistry,relProviderPluginRegistry,linkDiscovererRegistry,entityLinksPluginRegistry


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'linkDiscoverers' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'linkDiscoverers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry<org.springframework.hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverer, org.springframework.http.MediaType>' available: expected single matching bean but found 17: modelBuilderPluginRegistry,modelPropertyBuilderPluginRegistry,typeNameProviderPluginRegistry,syntheticModelProviderPluginRegistry,documentationPluginRegistry,apiListingBuilderPluginRegistry,operationBuilderPluginRegistry,parameterBuilderPluginRegistry,expandedParameterBuilderPluginRegistry,resourceGroupingStrategyRegistry,operationModelsProviderPluginRegistry,defaultsProviderPluginRegistry,pathDecoratorRegistry,apiListingScannerPluginRegistry,relProviderPluginRegistry,linkDiscovererRegistry,entityLinksPluginRegistry


***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:


Parameter 0 of method linkDiscoverers in org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration 
required a single bean, but 17 were found:
- modelBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
- modelPropertyBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
- typeNameProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
- syntheticModelProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
- documentationPluginRegistry: defined in null
- apiListingBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
- operationBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
- parameterBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
- expandedParameterBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
- resourceGroupingStrategyRegistry: defined in null
- operationModelsProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
- defaultsProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
- pathDecoratorRegistry: defined in null
- apiListingScannerPluginRegistry: defined in null
- relProviderPluginRegistry: defined by method 'relProviderPluginRegistry' in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfiguration.class]
- linkDiscovererRegistry: defined in null
- entityLinksPluginRegistry: defined by method 'entityLinksPluginRegistry' in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/WebMvcEntityLinksConfiguration.class]
```

What could have caused this issue ?

Note: I am not using HATEOAS in my `pom.xml` file.

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <swagger-springfox.version>2.9.2</swagger-springfox.version>
    <sonar.jacoco.execPath>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.execPath>
    <jasypt-spring-boot-starter>2.1.1</jasypt-spring-boot-starter>
    <logbook-spring-boot-starter>1.13.0</logbook-spring-boot-starter>
    <assertj-swagger>0.8.1</assertj-swagger>
    <jacoco-version>0.8.4</jacoco-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Use `mvn dependency:tree` and check if something else is pulling in the `Hateoas`  dependency. IRC If you use Spring Data REST that has a dependency on Spring Hateoas.

Comment: I have this same issue on the upgrade. I do know where the dependency is coming from but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001241/parameter-0-of-method-relprovider-in-org-springframework-hateoas-config-hateoas ?

Answer (score 72):

I had this issue with `Swagger + HATEOAS` in my `spring-boot` application.

The fix is given below (edit your Swagger configuration class):

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LinkDiscoverers discoverers() {
        List<LinkDiscoverer> plugins = new ArrayList<>();
        plugins.add(new CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer());
        return new LinkDiscoverers(SimplePluginRegistry.create(plugins));

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me as `_links` is turned into `links` and `_embedded` is turned into `content` in the response, therefore most of my mvcMock tests checking the `_links` are failing and the API is different from what's provided out of the box with spring-boot-starter-hateos

Comment: I had this happen as well. You need to enable Hal+json

Comment: lemon could you elaborate a bit please? I've tried to use of the `HalLinkDiscoverer` class instead of the `CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer` didn't do the trick and still my tests fail because links are rendered as `links` and not `_links`, as well as content is rendered as `content` and not the expected `_embedded`

Comment: The way I did it in my configuration java file was `@EnableHypermediaSupport(type=EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)` you must include `org.springframework.hateoas.config.EnableHypermediaSupport`. Not sure if it matters but I have as a dependency: spring-boot-starter-hateoas

Comment: @lemon Nice answer !! This works for spring-boot 2.3.0 + hateoas + Swagger 2.9.2

Comment: This solution worked for me.. but I am curious to know what is this exactly doing logically? with the issue? how it fixed it?

Comment: @lemon this saved my day. thank you. Can you please describe a bit about what it exactly does?

Comment: @Kerruba were you able to solve the issue? I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: @lemon your response fixed my issue but after adding ``EnableHypermediaSupport(type=EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)`` same issue started appearing again. I tried this because in reponse I was getting ``links`` instead if ``_links``

Comment: `SimplePluginRegistry.create()` seems to be deprecated. Is there an alternative to this?

Answer (score 21):

For me this link helped: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/731

In a nutshell i added to my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Also, in this tutorial, there is a reference to that dependency: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-hateoas-tutorial

Comment: That helped me a lot. However what I do not understand is that I was supposed to get this dependency from `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` but for some reason maven was not linking the transitive dependency. Suddenly after few hours I got this transitive dependency.

Answer (score 9):

```
    Use following 2 dependency to resolve Swagger and Hateoas dependency conflict.
    
    If Spring Boot version is >= 2.2.0 the use io.springfox version 3.0.0
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

After using version 3.0.0 swagger-ui will not be working so use following dependency and user /swagger-ui/ instead /swagger-ui.html

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: To solve my issue I had first to do what is described by @lemon and then upgrade Springfox dependencies to 3.0.0 and add the starter. Without this, I had multiple occurence of beans available and Spring Boot was not able to choose.

Answer (score 8):

This kind of issue is occurring due to a new feature of Hateoas.

If you want to solve this problem , just embed the following line of codes in your swagger configuration file.

```
@Primary
@Bean
public LinkDiscoverers discoverers() {
    List<LinkDiscoverer> plugins = new ArrayList<>();
    plugins.add(new CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer());
    return new LinkDiscoverers(SimplePluginRegistry.create(plugins));
}
```

I think this is gonna solve your problem as it solved mine.

Answer (score 6):

The issue faced with me when i using

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
.....
.....
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

with springfox swagger

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

if you take a look into spring hateoas dependencies there is a dependency on `spring-plugin-core` with version `2.0.0.RELEASE`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-plugin.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

but swagger dependency use `spring-plugin-core` with version `1.2.0.RELEASE`.

spring-boot have conflict on bean creation so, you need to unify the `org.springframework.plugin` version to make spring see it, If you choose `2.0.0.RELEASE` swagger will bot be able to compile,

so version `1.2.0.RELEASE` will be work for both dependencies, like

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

After that you need configuration class to initiate beans for `swagger` and `hateoas` like this:

```java
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LinkDiscoverers discoverers() {
        List<LinkDiscoverer> plugins = new ArrayList<>();
        plugins.add(new CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer());
        return new LinkDiscoverers(SimplePluginRegistry.create(plugins));
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket postsApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("{ApplicationName}")
                .apiInfo(buildApiInfo())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
                .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo buildApiInfo() {
        Contact contact = new Contact("CompanyName", "https://company-domain.com", "mail@company.com");
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title(""{ApplicationName}"")
                .description("API Description")
                .license("license")
                .version("1.0")
                .contact(contact)
                .licenseUrl("licenseURl")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked for me and I'm using `@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)` to have `"_links"` with underscores. I updated swagger version to `2.9.2`. However, I didn't need the `discovers()` method and it still works!

Answer (score 3):

try this version 2.6.1,i already solve with this way

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This didn't change anything for me, either.

Answer (score 3):

For Spring boot version `2.1.3.RELEASE` users, the following dependencies work fine for hateoas+swagger:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using springdoc-openapi and after having encountered this problem similar to the one mentioned here:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of method linkDiscoverers in org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration required a single bean, but 3 were found:
    - relProviderPluginRegistry: defined by method 'relProviderPluginRegistry' in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfiguration.class]
    - linkDiscovererRegistry: defined in null
    - entityLinksPluginRegistry: defined by method 'entityLinksPluginRegistry' in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/WebMvcEntityLinksConfiguration.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

I just add this dependency in my pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

hope that this can help someone

Answer (score 2):

You can change the version like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am working with Spring Boot 2.4.1. But you can not see Swagger endpoint log when starting Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 1):

Best Solution

Add below code in SwaggerConfig class

```
@Bean
public LinkDiscoverers discovers() {    
    List<LinkDiscoverer> plugins = new ArrayList<>();
    plugins.add(new CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer());
    return new LinkDiscoverers(SimplePluginRegistry.create(plugins));[enter image description here][1]  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting error

"Error creating bean with name 'halLinkDisocoverer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/mediatype/hal/HalMediaTypeConfiguration.class]"..

While Building a Hypermedia-Driven RESTful Web Service

Deletion of this dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
     <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

resolved my issue.

Check this link for more details
[Why i am getting an error Factory method 'halLinkDisocoverer' threw exception in springboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927183/why-i-am-getting-an-error-factory-method-hallinkdisocoverer-threw-exception-in)

Answer (score 1):

As [Alexander Weiß has already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59106652/265954), the `spring-plugin-core` dependency is resolved with the wrong version `1.2.0.RELEASE`.

In order to force usage of the correct `2.0.0.RELEASE`, you have to EITHER exclude the wrong transitive dependency and explicitly specify the correct one, OR to pin (!) that dependency version in your `pom.xml`. This is done in the `<dependenciesManagement>` block, not in the `<dependencies>` block. Pinning example for Springfox 3.0.0:

```xml
<properties>
    <spring-plugin-core.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring-plugin-core.version>
    <springfox.version>3.0.0</springfox.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- API Documentation -->
    <!-- Fix wrong resolved `spring-plugin-core` dependency version for springfox -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-plugin-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <!-- API Documentation -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I actually wanted hateoas support and had the same issue. Turned out this happens if you have

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Also want to point out there is a current incompatibility with hateoas + swagger + spring boot 2.2.0. You can run hateoas or swagger but not both. https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2932

Comment: Am not using hateoas, and dont require it either.  i even tried excluding hateoas dependency from spring web starter.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed these dependencies as a workaround and worked:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

please let me know if worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it, it was happening due to integration when Swagger + HATEOAS was used with Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE

```
package com.company.springbootworks.swagger;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverer;
import org.springframework.hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverers;
import org.springframework.hateoas.mediatype.collectionjson.CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.plugin.core.SimplePluginRegistry;

import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.DocExpansion;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ModelRendering;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.OperationsSorter;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.TagsSorter;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfigurationBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public LinkDiscoverers discoverers() {
        List<LinkDiscoverer> plugins = new ArrayList<>();
        plugins.add(new CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer());
        return new LinkDiscoverers(SimplePluginRegistry.create(plugins));

    }

    @Bean
    public Docket eDesignApi(SwaggerConfigProperties swaggerConfigProperties) {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(apiInfo(swaggerConfigProperties))
                .enable(Boolean.valueOf(swaggerConfigProperties.getEnabled())).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().pathMapping("/")
                .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class).genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(Boolean.valueOf(swaggerConfigProperties.getUseDefaultResponseMessages()))
                .enableUrlTemplating(Boolean.valueOf(swaggerConfigProperties.getEnableUrlTemplating()));
    }

    @Bean
    UiConfiguration uiConfig(SwaggerConfigProperties swaggerConfigProperties) {
        return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder().deepLinking(Boolean.valueOf(swaggerConfigProperties.getDeepLinking()))
                .displayOperationId(Boolean.valueOf(swaggerConfigProperties.getDisplayOperationId()))
                .defaultModelsExpandDepth(Integer.valueOf(swaggerConfigProperties.getDefaultModelsExpandDepth()))
                .defaultModelExpandDepth(Integer.valueOf(swaggerConfigProperties.getDefaultModelExpandDepth()))
                .defaultModelRendering(ModelRendering.EXAMPLE)
                .displayRequestDuration(Boolean.valueOf(swaggerConfigProperties.getDisplayRequestDuration()))
                .docExpansion(DocExpansion.NONE).filter(Boolean.valueOf(swaggerConfigProperties.getFilter()))
                .maxDisplayedTags(Integer.valueOf(swaggerConfigProperties.getMaxDisplayedTags()))
                .operationsSorter(OperationsSorter.ALPHA)
                .showExtensions(Boolean.valueOf(swaggerConfigProperties.getShowExtensions()))
                .tagsSorter(TagsSorter.ALPHA).supportedSubmitMethods(UiConfiguration.Constants.DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS)
                .validatorUrl(null).build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo(SwaggerConfigProperties swaggerConfigProperties) {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title(swaggerConfigProperties.getTitle())
                .description(swaggerConfigProperties.getDescription()).version(swaggerConfigProperties.getApiVersion())
                .build();
    }
}
```

and below are the swagger dependencies

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
    <swagger-annotations.version>1.5.21</swagger-annotations.version>
    <swagger-models.version>1.5.21</swagger-models.version>
    <spring-plugin.version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-plugin.version>
</properties>


<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger-annotations.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger-models.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: From where are you getting the SwaggerConfigProperties  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Swagger`, but can compromise with `HATEOAS`, then just remove the HATEOAS dependency and add:

```
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version:'2.9.2'  
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
```