# Error while deploying spring boot application on Weblogic server

Tags: spring-boot, hateoas

Facing the issue since I have added Hateoas dependency to my Spring boot project and deploying on weblogic server 12c

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2020-01-09 14:18:53,591
>   ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter
>   [[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue:
>   'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']
>
> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of method linkDiscoverers in org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration required a
>   single bean, but 15 were found:
>                   - modelBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
>                   - modelPropertyBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
>                   - typeNameProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
>                   - documentationPluginRegistry: defined in null
>                   - apiListingBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
>                   - operationBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
>                   - parameterBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
>                   - expandedParameterBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
>                   - resourceGroupingStrategyRegistry: defined in null
>                   - operationModelsProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
>                   - defaultsProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
>                   - pathDecoratorRegistry: defined in null
>                   - relProviderPluginRegistry: defined by method 'relProviderPluginRegistry' in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfiguration.class]
>                   - linkDiscovererRegistry: defined in null
>                   - entityLinksPluginRegistry: defined by method 'entityLinksPluginRegistry' in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/hateoas/config/WebMvcEntityLinksConfiguration.class]
>
> Action:
>
> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the
>   bean that should be consumed
>
> <09-Jan-2020, 2:18:53,633 PM IST>    ' available: expected single
>   matching bean but found 15:
>   modelBuilderPluginRegistry,modelPropertyBuilderPluginRegistry,typeNameProviderPluginRegistry,documentationPluginRegistry,apiListingBuilderPluginRegistry,operationBuilderPluginRegistry,parameterBuilderPluginRegistry,expandedParameterBuilderPluginRegistry,resourceGroupingStrategyRegistry,operationModelsProviderPluginRegistry,defaultsProviderPluginRegistry,pathDecoratorRegistry,relProviderPluginRegistry,linkDiscovererRegistry,entityLinksPluginRegistry
>                   at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
>                   at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
>                   at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
>                   at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
>                   at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>                   Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>           Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry' available: expected single
>   matching bean but found 15:
>   modelBuilderPluginRegistry,modelPropertyBuilderPluginRegistry,typeNameProviderPluginRegistry,documentationPluginRegistry,apiListingBuilderPluginRegistry,operationBuilderPluginRegistry,parameterBuilderPluginRegistry,expandedParameterBuilderPluginRegistry,resourceGroupingStrategyRegistry,operationModelsProviderPluginRegistry,defaultsProviderPluginRegistry,pathDecoratorRegistry,relProviderPluginRegistry,linkDiscovererRegistry,entityLinksPluginRegistry
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:220)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1265)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874)
>                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778)
>                   Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>           >
>           <09-Jan-2020, 2:18:53,674 PM IST>    
>           <09-Jan-2020, 2:18:53,775 PM IST>    
>           <09-Jan-2020, 2:18:53,834 PM IST>    
>           <09-Jan-2020, 2:18:53,981 PM IST>    
>           <09-Jan-2020, 2:18:53,988 PM IST>    
>           <09-Jan-2020, 2:18:53,992 PM IST>    
>           <09-Jan-2020, 2:18:54,0 PM IST>

POM.xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bt</groupId>
    <artifactId>Some project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>some Project</name>
    <description>REST enabled adapter to communicate with tetProject database</description>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>some Repo</id>
            <name><xyz.some.name></name>
            <url><xyz.some.url></url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
     </properties>
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commonlibs.com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commonlibs.com.bea.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.bea.core.datasource6_1.7.0.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commonlibs.com.bea.core.utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.bea.core.utils.wrapper_1.4.0.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <finalName>Some project</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Certainly it wouldn't hurt to read the entire [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page as well.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431876/spring-boot-2-2-0-spring-hateoas-startup-issue ?

Comment: Hi, before to study your problem I have a question for you: why do you deploy a spring-boot app in weblogic if a spring-boot application is a standalone application that create an own JEE container?

Answer (score 0):

### Spring is telling you the problem

```
org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration required a single bean,
    but 15 were found:
```

Which means that there are 15 methods that return a bean that fits HateoasConfiguration.

### Who are those bastards?

Spring continues right after with the list:

```
        - modelBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
        - modelPropertyBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
        - typeNameProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
        - documentationPluginRegistry: defined in null
        - apiListingBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
        - operationBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
        - parameterBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
        - expandedParameterBuilderPluginRegistry: defined in null
        - resourceGroupingStrategyRegistry: defined in null
        - operationModelsProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
        - defaultsProviderPluginRegistry: defined in null
        - pathDecoratorRegistry: defined in null
        - relProviderPluginRegistry: defined by method 'relProviderPluginRegistry' 
             in class path resource
             [org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfiguration.class]
        - linkDiscovererRegistry: defined in null
        - entityLinksPluginRegistry: defined by method 'entityLinksPluginRegistry'
             in class path resource
             [org/springframework/hateoas/config/WebMvcEntityLinksConfiguration.class]
```

The list might be not so clear or familiar as it might be that some of these methods are defined by the framework.

### So what can be done?

Spring is suggesting a solution:

```
 Action:

    Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary,
    updating the consumer to accept multiple beans,
    or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

### Does it mean that I need to reconfigure my `@Bean`s?

Not necessarily. First try to see [if someone else faced the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431876/spring-boot-2-2-0-spring-hateoas-startup-issue).

You may find the solution there.