# Spring Boot 2.2.4 springdoc OpenApi Swagger V3 hateoas issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, springdoc, swagger-3.0

After integrating the [springdoc-openapi-data-rest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-data-rest/1.4.4) library to map Pageable(spring-date-commons) object to correct URL-Parameter in Swagger UI I encountered this problem:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method linkDiscoverers in org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration required a single bean, but 3 were found:
    - relProviderPluginRegistry: defined by method 'relProviderPluginRegistry' in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfiguration.class]
    - linkDiscovererRegistry: defined in null
    - entityLinksPluginRegistry: defined by method 'entityLinksPluginRegistry' in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/WebMvcEntityLinksConfiguration.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed


Process finished with exit code 0
```

please how could I effectively solve this problem ? thanks

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue by adding this dependency in pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431876/spring-boot-2-2-0-spring-hateoas-startup-issue/63648274#63648274)

Hope this could help someone

Comment: Also if you are only using spring-hateoas, make sure you use springdoc-openapi-hateoas instead of springdoc-openapi-data-rest.